# Does a pointer move on to the next line in an array on its own if in a loop?

Tags: c

In my program, pointer is an address on the first line of text in a file, pointer_ew is an address on the third line of text in a file. I am trying to print the text in between the addresses in a different file. I was wondering does the pointer move on to the next line on its own when it encounters a new line or a null character? If no, please explain what kind of errors would the following code lead to?

```
 int m=row_ew[pick_ew]; /* m is equal to 2, which is the address to the first element of the third row in the array*/ 
 int n=pos_ew[pick_ew]; /* n is equal to the index of the word in the third line to increment the pointer position to the address of the first character of the word*/

 pointer_ew=file[m]+n+strlen(endword); /* Add the length of the word to increment the pointer to the end of the word*/

 pointer=file[i]; /*i is 0, address to the first element of the first row in the array*/

 while(pointer!=pointer_ew)
 {
   fputc(*pointer,outfile);
   pointer++;
 }
```

It is working fine, but I dont see the random characters in the file I am trying to copy from. But I do see it in the file to which I am copying to. At the beginning of the line, in the output file I see some extra random characters (<´ri ) along with the copied text.

Comment: No, a pointer know nothing about file i/o. You are writing whatever is at that address at the time.  Since you do not show a [mcve], had to determine what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have added a bit of code, all I am trying to do is copy and paste a part of a file in another file. The addresses are on two different lines in the file.

Comment: @AMD I'm guessing it should work

Comment: @CharlesShiller: It works, but I see some random characters at the beginning of the line.

Comment: check how you got your file[i]

Comment: @CharlesShiller: It is working fine and showing me the text I am looking for, except I see some random characters at the beginning of the line.

Comment: I'm guessing that when you're reading from file into `file[i]`, it's starting reading into `file[i][4]` or something.

Comment: @CharlesShiller: My file[i] is fine, I know that because I printed it out and checked it.

Answer (score 1):

In a text file, a "newline" is a regular character, either 10 (`\n`) in Unix like systems, 12 (`\r`) on old Macs, or 10 12 (`\r\n`) on Dos or Windows.

This should copy the file, character by character, whatever you have, until you hit the end pointer (note, I'm not sure what you're doing, but if `pointer_ew` doesn't point to a part of your original string[1], your program will try outputting whatever is in RAM until the OS will kill your program with a segfault).

[1]. As in, if you *didn't* define pointer_ew in terms of `pointer` (as something like `pointer_ew = pointer+5`). If pointer_ew points to another string, you'll get a Segmentation Fault.

Comment: I'm guessing it should work (if you don't have a memory issue there). But the main point is still true. If you write char by char, newlines don't matter - they're just another char.

Comment: It is working fine, but I dont see the random characters in the file I am trying to copy from. But I do see it in the file to which I am copying to.